# Does anyone know how to get a class specification of the GlueLogger class

Tags: aws-glue

My team is creating glue spark jobs in python, and I've discovered that the glue logger you obtain using the following calls is not the same as the log4j logger class you would get if you were using pure spark.

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
logger.info("info message")
logger.warn("warn message")
logger.error("error message")
```

For example, it throws an "attribute not found" error if you try to use logger.debug or logger.fatal

Since I'm trying to integrate this logger with our existing code logging framework, just having a class specification of what methods and attributes it supports would be a huge help.

Does anyone know where I can get this information? Our team does not have access to AWS support so I can't raise a ticket to ask them directly.

I've tried tracking down the sources, but aws-glue-libs calls into a glue java class that I cannot locate either the sources or the jar for glue `java_import(sc._jvm, "com.amazonaws.services.glue.log.GlueLogger")`

I've studied the aws-glue-libs python library, and tried introspecting the aws-java-sdk-glue-1.12.128.jar library, but cannot locate the class in question there.